# Is there any kind of database that saves citations together with the text that they are attached to?

Tags: academia

Let's say I have a paper A that cites a paper B. Two explicit citation in paper A might look like this:

> Recently it has been shown that electrons exists [reference to paper B].

and

> Electrons have a mass of 9.10938356(11)×10−31 kg [reference to paper B].

What I'm looking for is a database that would contain entries like this

```
{
    "source": "ID_of_paper_A",
    "target": "ID_of_paper_B",
    "text": [
        "Recently it has been shown that electrons exists",
        "Electrons have a mass of 9.10938356(11)×10−31 kg"
    ]
}
```

If there is no such database, is there any hope to extract this kind of information using some form of web scraping? Considering the amount of papers that sit behind paywalls, I have the suspicion this would no be feasible.

Comment: there are **many** academic paper APIs where you can build this network. No scraping necessary, and for the article metadata, you shouldn't need paywall access. Full text is another story.

Comment: Hey @philshem, can you give me a link or even just a hint of where to find these APIs? The only ones that I can find only contain the information about which paper cites which, but do not include any information about the text that these citations are attached to.

Comment: @BenjaminWeigang See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/115/82581